# using icacls in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions

I want to make a batch file which applies permissions to a given user folder using icacls. This is the batch file i made :

```
@echo off

set /p username=Enter username:

echo Select permissions :

echo N  - no access
echo F  - full access
echo M  - modify access
echo RX - read and exe
echo R  - read-only acc
echo W  - write-only ac
echo D  - delete access

echo.

set /p perm=Enter permissions:

if %perm%==F

icacls "C:\Users\%username%" /grant:r "%username%:(OI)(CI)F"
```

When i run this file and enter permissions as F, it displays this **error : The syntax of the command is incorrect.** but if i run the same command directly in cmd it works perfectly. So, how do i correct the command in batch file so that it runs without any issues?

Comment: Here's one reminder: N (no access) never works in icacls command arguments. N is for display only and is a shorthand of `(DENY)(F)`. There's no other use than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the syntax of your `if` command is causing the problems. You are checking if the permission chosen is `F` but then not doing anything with it.

Try either putting it on one line

```
if %perm%==F icacls "C:\Users\%username%" /grant:r "%username%:(OI)(CI)F"
```

or in brackets

```
if %perm%==F (
icacls "C:\Users\%username%" /grant:r "%username%:(OI)(CI)F"
)
```

Comment: May be not suitable place for comment but can you give me working example of icacls command not to access folder for everyone